# extend log4j2.xml and split it when it become very long

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

My log4j2.xml file becomes very lenghthy so I want to open a new xml file to add the appenders I want,

I tried

```
<import resource="log4j2_2.xml"/>
```

inside the Configuration tag but it does not work
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple configuration files and merge the by specifying them as a comma separated list in the Log4J.configurationFile property.